# VBA Visio select object within 1 line of the schematic (or by color)

Tags: vba, visio

I would like to select an object just within 1 line instead of the whole schematic I have.

So far I used the selection by object ID

```
If Vshp.Name Like "*UG*" Then
Debug.Print Vshp.ID & " - " & Vshp.Master.Name
sel.Select Vshp, visSelect
'sel.Selection.Align visHorzAlignNone, visVertAlignMiddle, False
End If
Next
```

but it looks like everything I apply thereafter refers to the primarily selected shape, which is underneath.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.align

In the image, I marked the example of the area I would like to have selected. Then apply the changes. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to grab this particular section of my schematic.

Is there a way of selecting the bunch of objects for example by their color? Or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate objects on page by layers. Each layer can have color.
[image: Visio layer properties window]
You can use [Create Selection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.master.createselection) with option by layer.
With syntax like

```
 Dim vsoLayer As Visio.Layer
    Dim vsoSelection As Visio.Selection
    Dim sh as visio.shape

    Set vsoLayer = ActivePage.Layers.ItemU("a")
    Set vsoSelection = ActivePage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeByLayer, visSelModeSkipSuper, vsoLayer)
```

Also you can select multiple layers with code

```
Dim vsoSelection1 As Visio.Selection
Set vsoSelection1 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.CreateSelection(visSelTypeByLayer, visSelModeSkipSuper, "a;c")
Application.ActiveWindow.Selection = vsoSelection1
```

---

You wrote

> I used the selection by object ID

There is selection by name, if shape name contain **UG**...

---

I took a close look at your picture.
[image: Stranges]
I'm not sure that you can programmatically determine which branch which figures belong to.

For example **NRTH-X-AF01BB**!
there are two lines on the input: yellow and red.
The output are two yellow lines.

I have found that it is better to manually assign shapes to certain layers...

Comment: Your solution triggers another question - how to create layers in Visio programmatically.

Comment: No, it is just suggestion use layers! My codes are showing how select single and multiple existing layer(s)...

Comment: I would rather to avoid layers and use something like ordering from the very top

Comment: What do you mean as _ordering from the very top_?

Comment: I wish I could send you my file and explain to you all the steps I need to resolve. Once I have the schematic, I need to have the elements selected not in the standard manner, but rather in sections (divided by colors or "levels" in which they have been drew).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a telepath. I don't understand what `levels` are in your context? Post a simple document with no confidential information in the cloud and share the link

Comment: Please try to use this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjsi5cpy61wl5bi/Sample%20scematic2E.vsdm?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for share your document, it helped for answer in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056627/vba-visio-cannot-change-font-size-in-the-element)! But i dont understand 'level' meaning...

Comment: I mean, the particular "branch" of the schematic. As you can see, you have the main joint, from which a dozen or so branches come out. They're usually in one colour, in which I would like to base my selection for further alignment.

Comment: I changed my answer a few years ago. But I just now realized that in your example, some shapes were not aligned correctly

Comment: Is there a chance to pick them up by color? How could I investigate to which group this color belongs to?

Comment: You mean when use layers? If so, that not so complex! Just iterate layers, chech their colors, show user form where you can select some color... Just as idea